# Cannot connect through WebSockets with nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, google-chrome, websocket

My setup consists in a headless Chrome instance running on http://localhost:9222. It works if I connect to it directly through a WebSocket client.

I would like to put a Nginx server block as a proxy in front of it (I'll add authentication, etc, later).

My configuration is:

```
server {
    # Logic configuration

    server_name chrome.example.eu;

    access_log /opt/chrome/access.log;
    error_log /opt/chrome/error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9222;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        location /devtools/page/ {
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_read_timeout 86400;
        }
    }

    # Networking

    listen 80;
}
```

The HTTP part works fine. The Chrome devtools' UI is displaying if I open http://chrome.mydomain.eu. However, the websocket connection can't be established.

The browser tries to connect to `ws://chrome.example.eu/devtools/page/6877e641-fc1e-4196-bb55-0c3e1608af4a` but the server does not upgrade to a WebSocket connection. Nginx sends back a 404 response, and the error.log contains a line that I can't understand:

> *690 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/devtools/page/6877e641-fc1e-4196-bb55-0c3e1608af4a" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 130.79.192.16, server: chrome.example.eu, request: "GET /devtools/page/6877e641-fc1e-4196-bb55-0c3e1608af4a HTTP/1.1", host: "chrome.example.eu"

Why would nginx try to open a static file as there is no `try_files`? And why nginx isn't letting the Chrome instance handle that request (and it works in the parent location block)?

I feel I'm missing something simple, but I tried lots of little variations without success.

Subsidiary question: also, can I get rid of the child location block when the browser asks for a ws:// stream? (that is, automatic protocol upgrade without having to hardcode the WebSocket URL) -- And don't hesitate if you have any other kind of recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the proxy_pass for your child location?
As far as I know, content handlers are not inherited.

Comment: Yes, tried that, I forgot to mention it. Just retried, I think it's better because nginx does not send a 404 anymore, but the server just does not respond. The request is sent, but then, nothing, the websockets stays in "connecting" state.